# Does Spring Data Flow and Spring Cloud Stream is what I need to build a data processing pipeline with Choreography approach?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am planning to implement a data processing pipeline using the Microservice Architecture in Java. Since I have been using Spring boot to implement some of the Microservice already, I am investigating the rest of Spring components to see which one can help me to address my requirements. I have found out Spring Cloud Stream helps me to implement my solution using the event-driven approach, but I am not quite sure whether Spring Data Flow acts as a Single Point of Failure and does the orchestration of the microservices or it actually acts as a tool to help with visualizing the pipeline and deployment to Kubernetes, Cloud Foundry, etc. and still work passively outside the pipeline. Therefore, if it is failed for any reason, the pipeline can work without any interruptions.

To clarify what I am asking for, does the combination of Spring Cloud Stream and Spring Cloud Data Flow provide an almost similar approach to what this article refers to it as a best of both worlds of Orchestration and Choreography?

https://www.sapientglobalmarkets.com/blog/big-data-pipeline-orchestration-choreography